# Problems installing django-toolbelt

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, heroku, openssl

I'm trying to install `django-toolbelt` in my virtual-env per heroku django install instructions, but I keep getting the following error.

This is on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 - so I'm not sure what's the issue. I've tried fiddling with my ubuntu install to add in any dependencies that I might be missing, but nothing seems to have worked. Any help will be appreciated!

```
(venv)khalid@khalid-laptop:~/Desktop/Projects/heroku-test$ pip install django-toolbelt
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/Projects/heroku-test/venv/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/Projects/heroku-test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/Projects/heroku-test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2279, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/Projects/heroku-test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1989, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/Projects/heroku-test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.backwardcompat import walk_packages, console_to_str
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/Projects/heroku-test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/backwardcompat.py", line 18, in <module>
    import md5 as md5_module
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/md5.py", line 10, in <module>
    from hashlib import md5
ImportError: cannot import name md5
```

Comment: Which version of Python and django-toolbelt?

Comment: @thebjorn python 2.7; django-toolbelt I'll have to track down - it's whatever is in the Ubuntu repos. I'm pretty sure this is related to some SSL library being missing from Ubuntu though, and not related to django per se.

Comment: All the names mentioned should be part of the regular Python `hashlib`.  On thee third to last line, it is importing `md5.py` from `/usr/lib/python2.7/md5.py`, wich is not in your virtualenv...

Comment: @thebjorn "pip install md5" returns the same error in the virtualenv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After bashing my head for a bit, I ended up deleting my `virtualenv` folder, reinstalling `python-virtualenv` and creating a fresh one with the `--no-site-packages` flag, and I was able to install `django-toolbelt` successfully.

Comment: Please accept your answer so we can cite it in other, similar questions. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @jww sorry, stackoverflow didn't let me do it the day of, and I forgot after that. It's been accepted now :)